# Black line on top of image (Tailwind css)

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

[black line above image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IRkp.png)I am trying to create a product card using Tailwind CSS for styling. Whenever I get the image in the place that I want, there is a black line at the very top of the card/image. I have tried taking out all of the styles concerning my  tag and it still seems to be there. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import coffeemerch from "../images/Coffee-Product photo.jpg";

export default function Products() {
  return (

<div className="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl  top-40 left-32">
      <figure> <img className=" h-80 justify-center " src={coffeemerch} alt="coffee-product"></img></figure>
    <div className="card-body">
      <h2 className="card-title text-red-800">Medium Roast</h2>
    </div>
</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't see any  issue with this code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/abPznfD9A3

Comment: Can you try to re-generate this problem in a codesandbox and provide us with a link?

Comment: I went ahead and added a screenshot of the image with the line. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I guess it's the image itself which has the black line at the top. Because the code is just fine

Comment: can you try to share a screenshot with any other image. I guess that image has that black line.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] in your question.